# sTunnel failure to start

Tags: openssl, unix

im a bit stuck and need help understanding what im being told as there is nothing in the log file, i get the following error when i try and run stunnel (servermode):

sudo /etc/init.d/stunnel4 start

```
>     [....] Starting stunnel4 (via systemctl): stunnel4.serviceJob for stunnel4.service failed because the control process exited with error
> code. See "systemctl status stunnel4.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
> details. failed!
```

This is the conf file

...

```
; * Global options                                                              
*
;     **************************************************************************

; It is recommended to drop root privileges if stunnel is started by root
;setuid = stunnel4
;setgid = stunnel4

sslVersion = all

; PID file is created inside the chroot jail (if enabled)
pid = /var/run/stunnel.pid 

setuid = Jamie

cert = /etc/stunnel/private.pem
[jamietest]

accept = 10.0.2.15:5559
connect = 127.0.0.1:80

Debugging stuff (may be useful for troubleshooting)
foreground = yes
debug = 7 
output = /etc/stunnel/stunnel.log

; Enable FIPS 140-2 mode if needed for compliance
;fips = yes


;CRLfile = FILL IN THIS **

; Enable support for the insecure SSLv3 protocol
;options = -NO_SSLv3

; These options provide additional security at some performance degradation
;options = SINGLE_ECDH_USE
;options = SINGLE_DH_USE

;include = /etc/stunnel/conf
```

Comment: What does running `systemctl status stunnel4.service` and `journalctl -xe` give you?

Comment: a load of symbols

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out

The stunnel.conf was located in /etc/stunnel, but the actual stunnel program was looking for it in /usr/etc/

i'm glad ive figured it but I dont really understand what the difference is and the detail surrounding these two paths...anyone?